# c# log in page verifying from a database

Tags: c#, authentication

I'm new to c#, and I'm trying to create a log in page where a user enters a user name and password.  Then, this is read from a database to verify that the user_name and password are in there. I've set up the connection, and it seems to be working, because in this code, if I enter the title of the column, it will let me log in but not any of the values from that column. How do i get it to be the values it accepts?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace BrokerSolution
{
    public partial class LogIn : Form
    {
        public static String User ;
        public static String pass;
        public LogIn()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }

      private bool ValidateFunction(string User, string pass)
        {
            bool boolReturnvalue = false;
            String strConnection = "Server=****; Database=*****; User Id=******; password=*****";
            SqlConnection UGIcon = new SqlConnection(strConnection);
            String LogInQuery = "SELECT user_name, sign_in FROM Users";
            SqlCommand loginCommand = new SqlCommand(LogInQuery, UGIcon);
            SqlDataReader dr;
            UGIcon.Open();
            dr = loginCommand.ExecuteReader();

            while (dr.Read())
            {
                if ((User == dr["user_name"].ToString()) & (pass == dr["sign_in"].ToString()))
                {
                    boolReturnvalue = true;
                }

                dr.Close();
                return boolReturnvalue;


            }
            return boolReturnvalue;
        }
         private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            User = UsernametextBox.Text; //
            pass = PasswordtextBox.Text;
             SqlDataReader dr;
            if (User.Equals(_40029562DataSet.users.user_nameColumn.ToString()))
            {new Dashboard().Show();}
            else
            {
                new NewQuote().Show();
            }



        }




    }
}
```

Comment: you're getting all the columns, use something like "SELECT user_name FROM Users WHERE sign_in = @password AND user_name = @username" and thus if nothing is returned they gave bad credentials

Comment: also just return true when you find a hit in your if statement, the rest of the while loop would be unecessary at that point

Answer (score 0):

Try putting this in your button subroutine:

```
        User = UsernametextBox.Text; //
        pass = PasswordtextBox.Text;
        if (ValidateFunction(User,pass))
        {new Dashboard().Show();}
        else
        {
            new NewQuote().Show();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the Database on a remote host? You more than likely have to add your ip to the whitelist on  your database so that you can connect. I had that exact problem a few weeks ago, could access the tables and column names even, but no records.

If it is a local database simply use Windows Authentication. Otherwise attempt a telnet connection test in windows run console to attempt to ping the server.